# How do we write a function whose domain is two distinct elements drawn from a set of three?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $G$ be the group $G=C_3,+$ with an order relation $>$ which is unrelated to the group operation, having elements $\{0,1,2\}$ with addition modulo $3$ and let $C_2\in\{0,1\}$ with addition modulo $2$.

I can write a theorem in words:  If we identify any singleton element $x_1\in G$ then the remaining two elements are an ordered pair.

Therefore I can define a function $f(x_1,x_2)\to C_2,>$ that takes two *distinct* elements of $C_3$ and returns $f(x_1,x_2)\in \{0,1\}$ indicating whether $x_2$ is the greater or smaller element in the order inherited on $C_3\setminus \{x_1\}$.

$f(x_1,3)=1$ for either choice of $x_1$

$f(x_1,1)=0$ for either choice of $x_1$

$f(x_1,2)\in\{0,1\}$ depending on the choice of $x_1$

But how is the domain of this function best written?  None of the options I have come up with seem satisfactory.  I'm struggling to express that its domain is any two *distinct* elements drawn from $S_3$:

$C_3\times C_2\to C_2$ seems unsatisfactory because $C_2$ in the domain is really "the ordered pair $C_3\setminus x\in C_3$, and moreover, this is just the identity function $x\in C_2\mapsto x\in C_2$

$S_3\times C_3\to C_2$ is unsatisfactory because $C_3\times C_3\to C_2$ isn't defined for $x+y:y=x$

How should I best express that the domain requires a choice of distinct elements of the same set?

Comment: Usually people write $S_n$ for the symmetric group in $n$-letters.

Comment: @take008 thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: In this case, is there a reason you don't extend the domain and have the function just check $a<b$ or $a\le b$, to taste? If this was a toy example, I guess rage the complement of the [diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_functor).

Comment: @MarkS. I couldn't find a way of writing *the subset of* $\leq:C_3\times C_3\to C_2$ that wasn't really clunky.

Comment: Describe the order of group - linear, partial, antichain, circular?

Comment: @WilliamElliot $0<1<2$, nothing more than that.  Reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric over the given transversal of the cosets if you like (although I defined the group as acting on singleton integers rather than cosets).

Comment: G cannot be an ordered group.  G is a group associated with an order that is unrelated to the group operation.

Comment: Sorry @WilliamElliot , my terminology coincided with a terminology I didn't know existed.  I've now fixed.

Comment: The domain you are looking for is a subset of $C_3\times C_3.$ The least “clunky” way to notate it might be to give it a name such as $D$ and describe in words which subset it is.